# Returning "" in lieu of a proper string

Tags: .net, exception

In some methods returning strings, I have often seen "" returned if the actual string (Say a filepath), cannot be generated.

Is this in lieu of throwing an exception? Is there room for this sort of practise? Also, is this not what .NET does because if I can't get a proper string from one of its methods, I just see "".

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One general guideline I've seen is that, **Exceptions should be Exceptional!**

In some cases an empty string seems like a reasonable state for the application to be in.  You might want to handle that state (checking for String.IsNullOrEmpty()) but it doesn't nessecarily warrent an exception.

At least, in my opinion anyway, there are times when a "" is more appropriate than an exception.  I have had this exact argument in a production environment and I will say that the local devs were pretty split on the subject.

Comment: +1: I will also use a -1 to return an int when a zero (0) would otherwise be considered an acceptable value...anyway...+1

Comment: string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace in .net 4.0 is a better option than null or empty as it all checks for strings of the pattern "  ".